# Formatting text in a QTextEdit based on selection, instead of on the character before the cursor

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtextedit

I've been assembling a text editor based on [this example](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/building-a-text-editor-with-pyqt-part-one/143) by Peter Goldsborough, but modified for the PyQt bindings of Qt for Python.

In Goldsborough's code, there are a number of text-formatting methods that follow this pattern:

```
 def bold(self):
    if self.text.fontWeight() == QtGui.QFont.Bold:
        self.text.setFontWeight(QtGui.QFont.Normal)
    else:
        self.text.setFontWeight(QtGui.QFont.Bold)
```

The if/else is *supposed* to check what the format of the current selection is; if it's not yet the format that the method implements, it sets it to that format, otherwise, if it is already that format, it sets it back to normal again. Typical toggleable formatting behavior for a word processor.

Unfortunately this implementation does not appear to do quite that. The `fontWeight()` method retrieves the "current" format for the QTextBrowser, which means the format that it will render newly typed text in - in other words, continuing from the format of whatever is just *before* the cursor.

This means that there will be weird behavior which is not right for a word processor: if the text is all normal, then it will change formats fine, but if you change the format of an internal segment of text, then try to change it back afterwards, the text will erroneously remain in the formatted state.

Ideally what should happen is that the if/else should operate on the formatting of the text *inside* the selection instead of right before it. But I cannot find a method that does this. Thinking that I have missed something substantial along the way here - thank you for any suggestions you may have!

Comment: What if the selected text is not all formatted the same way?

Comment: The same behavior results. Depending on whether the character right before the selection has the particular formatting property or not, all of the selected text is set to not have the property, or have the property, respectively.

Comment: No, I mean for your desired behavior.  How can you have an if/else operating on "the formatting inside the selection" if the selection contains multiple kinds of formatting?

Comment: I can think of a number of ways - you could operate on the first character, or detect any formatting of the desired type within the selection as "formatted" that way, the same way many word processors handle it. But any of these ideas still require the ability to work with the characters within the selection rather than just before it.